# Matrix integral in multi-matrix model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, matrix-model

Though it is a mathematical problem, maybe more physicists know it well.

In quiver matrix model which is reviewed [DV](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0207106v1) or [CKR](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0311258v2), the path integral reduce to the matrix integral
$$Z \sim \int \prod_{i=1}^r d\Phi_i \prod_{<a,b>} dQ_{ab} e^{-\frac{1}{g_s} \rm{Tr} W(\Phi,Q)}$$
where $Q_{ab}$ are complex $N_a\times N_b$ matrces satisfying $Q_{ab}^\dagger=Q_{ba}$, and $\Phi_i$ are $N_i\times N_i$ matrices. $W$ is given by
$$W(\Phi,Q) =\sum_{i,j=1}^{r} s_{ij}Q_{ij} \Phi_jQ_{ji} +\sum_{i=1}^{r} W_i{\Phi_i} $$
where the constants $s_{ij}$ are antisymmetric,  $s_{ij}=-s_{ji}$, they obey
$s_{ij} = 1$ if $i < j$ and the nodes in the quiver diagram are linked, and $s_{ij} = 0$ otherwise. The notation $<a,b>$ for the range of the product denotes all pairs $(a, b)$ with $1 ≤ a, b ≤ r$ s.t. $s_{ab}\neq 0$. In order to calculate the path integral, first integrate out $Q_{ab}$:
$$ \int \prod_{(a,b)\in E}[dQ_{ab}dQ_{ba}] \exp \sum_{(a,b)\in E}-\frac{s_{ab}}{g_s}\rm{Tr} (Q_{ab}\Phi_b Q_{ba}-Q_{ba}\Phi_a Q_{ab})$$
where$E=\{(a,b)|1 ≤ a< b ≤ r\}$

**My question is** how to integrat $Q$ out to obtain something like $$ \det (\Phi_a\otimes 1-1\otimes \Phi_b)^{-1}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cross-posted from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/600896/11127 and http://mathoverflow.net/q/151344/13917

Comment: Dear Craig Thone. In general, it is frown upon to cross-post simultaneously, because it may waste potential answerer's time. As a minimum OP should mention the cross-posts (on all sites!). The preferred procedure is to not cross-post, and if the post hasn't received an acceptable answer after, say, a couple of days, then OP could flag for migration.

Comment: @Qmechanic, I am very sorry for this. What should I do? Delete some of them? or...